# Can anyone recommend an efficient UDP messaging framework for Java?

Tags: java, messaging

I need to be able to send compact messages (ideally small enough to fit into a single UDP packet) from Java.  It needs to be as efficient as possible - can anyone give me any pointers (other than constructing them manually)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Mina -- http://mina.apache.org/udp-tutorial.html -- very good tool

Comment: I'm using it on a chat server for high-latency, low bandwidth, jittery frameworks.